# Mule Groovy script file location works in Studio but not standalone

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I have a groovy scripting transformer that is in a file stored under src\main\resources.
    `<scripting:transformer doc:name="myXform">

        <scripting:script engine="Groovy"
            file="src\main\resources\myTransform.groovy">

        </scripting:script>

    </scripting:transformer>`
My project works as expected within Mule Studio. When I deploy it to the standalone Mule server it fails to deploy as it cannot find the relative file location.
*Failed to load "src\main\resources\myTransform.groovy" from classpath or file system*

I have a couple of questions:
- Is this the appropriate place to keep my groovy transforms?
- How do I fix the problem because in the deployed version the src\main\resources exists under META-INF?
- If it is a classpath setting then what do I change to fix it (.classpath, system variable on standalone server, etc.) ?

Thank you.

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Ok, I reinstalled Mule Studio (Version: 3.5.0 Build Id: 201312091746) and built (using Maven) a vanilla project from scratch:
    `

```
<mule xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting" xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.4.1"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/current/mule-scripting.xsd">
    <flow name="gpFlow1" doc:name="gpFlow1">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="H:\DCH_ESB_Test\InMuleTest" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="FileIn"/>
        <byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>
        <scripting:transformer doc:name="Groovy">
            <scripting:script engine="Groovy" file="myTransform.groovy"/>
        </scripting:transformer>
        <file:outbound-endpoint path="H:\DCH_ESB_Test\OutMuleTest" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="FileOut"/>
    </flow>
</mule>`
```

myTransform.groovy simply contains `return payload.toUpperCase()`
  The first thing I see is Studio does not like the non-pathed file and flags an error  on the scripting transformer of: "*Path does not exist*".
However, when I run the project within Studio it works.
When deployed I still get:
`    ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    + New app 'gp'                                             +
    ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    INFO  2014-02-13 10:05:47,282 [Mule.app.deployer.monitor.1.thread.1] org.mule.module.launcher.MuleApplicationClassLoader: [gp] Loading the following jars:
    =============================
    file:/C:/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.3.0/apps/gp/lib/asm-3.1.jar
    file:/C:/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.3.0/apps/gp/lib/cloveretl-engine-3.4.1.jar
    file:/C:/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.3.0/apps/gp/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
    file:/C:/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.3.0/apps/gp/lib/ftplet-api-1.0.2.jar
    file:/C:/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.3.0/apps/gp/lib/ftpserver-core-1.0.2.jar
    file:/C:/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.3.0/apps/gp/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.5.jar
    file:/C:/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.3.0/apps/gp/lib/jaxb-xjc-2.2.5.1.jar
    file:/C:/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.3.0/apps/gp/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.1.jar
    file:/C:/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.3.0/apps/gp/lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar
    file:/C:/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.3.0/apps/gp/lib/mina-core-2.0.0-M6.jar
    file:/C:/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.3.0/apps/gp/lib/mockito-all-1.9.0.jar
    file:/C:/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.3.0/apps/gp/lib/mockobjects-core-0.09.jar
    file:/C:/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.3.0/apps/gp/lib/mule-core-ee-3.4.1.jar
    file:/C:/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.3.0/apps/gp/lib/mule-module-boot-ee-3.4.1.jar
    file:/C:/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.3.0/apps/gp/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
    file:/C:/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.3.0/apps/gp/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar
    file:/C:/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.3.0/apps/gp/lib/spring-tx-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
    file:/C:/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.3.0/apps/gp/lib/spring-web-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
    file:/C:/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.3.0/apps/gp/lib/sshd-core-0.6.0.jar
    =============================

```
ERROR 2014-02-13 10:05:49,294 [Mule.app.deployer.monitor.1.thread.1] org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentService: Failed to deploy application archive: gp.zip  
org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: InitialisationException: Failed to load "myTransform.groovy" from classpath or file system  
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:220)  
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.ApplicationWrapper.init(ApplicationWrapper.java:64)  
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultMuleDeployer.deploy(DefaultMuleDeployer.java:46)  
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentService.guardedDeploy(DeploymentService.java:398)  
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentService.deploy(DeploymentService.java:365)  `
```

My .classpath file within Studio looks like:
    `<classpath>

      <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/app" excluding="**/*.java"/>

      <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java"/>

      <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/resources" excluding="**/*.java"/>

      <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/test/java" output="target/test-classes"/>

      <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/test/resources" output="target/test-classes" excluding="**/*.java"/>

      <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>

      <classpathentry kind="con" path="MULE_RUNTIME"/>

      <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>

      <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/asm/asm/3.1/asm-3.1.jar"/>

      <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/com/cloveretl/cloveretl-engine/3.4.1/cloveretl-engine-3.4.1.jar"/>

      <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar"/>

      <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/ftpserver/ftplet-api/1.0.2/ftplet-api-1.0.2.jar"/>

      <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/ftpserver/ftpserver-core/1.0.2/ftpserver-core-1.0.2.jar"/>

      <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.1.5/jaxb-impl-2.1.5.jar"/>

      <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-xjc/2.2.5.1/jaxb-xjc-2.2.5.1.jar"/>

      <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.6.1/jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.1.jar"/>

      <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/com/jcraft/jsch/0.1.42/jsch-0.1.42.jar"/>

      <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/mina/mina-core/2.0.0-M6/mina-core-2.0.0-M6.jar"/>

      <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/mockito/mockito-all/1.9.0/mockito-all-1.9.0.jar"/>

      <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/mockobjects/mockobjects-core/0.09/mockobjects-core-0.09.jar"/>

      <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/com/mulesoft/muleesb/mule-core-ee/3.4.1/mule-core-ee-3.4.1.jar"/>

      <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/com/mulesoft/muleesb/modules/mule-module-boot-ee/3.4.1/mule-module-boot-ee-3.4.1.jar"/>

      <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.1/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar"/>

      <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.6.1/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar"/>

      <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/springframework/spring-tx/3.0.6.RELEASE/spring-tx-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar"/>

      <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/springframework/spring-web/3.0.6.RELEASE/spring-web-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar"/>

      <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/sshd/sshd-core/0.6.0/sshd-core-0.6.0.jar"/>

    </classpath>`
In the export zip file, myTransform.groovy is found under:
gp.zip\META-INF\src\main\resources\
I did not reinstall my standalone.

Thanks,
-- Don

Answer (score 5):

I came across a similar issue, and I can blame mule examples, I was trying to use parse template deployed ok on mule studio but when I tried stand alone. The example set the location in the xml of template on /src/main/resources/responseXml.template which works ok on mule studio. However on stand alone mule cannot find the template and fails to deploy. I found this is **PROJECT'S STRUCTURE**  related issue rather than mule's issue (google io exception /src/main/resource). It seems that when one generate the deployable file resource files are move to the project's root, and location should be just responseXml.template (or whateverresource.file) and no path, this worked for me on studio and standalone.
Just tested successfully with groovy on studio, I created

```
/src/main/resources/example.groovy
```

and on the xml:

```
<scripting:script engine="Groovy" file="example.groovy"/>
```

in a couple of hours I will test it with groovy on standalone....

Answer (score 0):

You have the correct folder to put a Mule script, but you should not include the path to the folder, just "myTransform.groovy". Right-click the project in Studio and see Properties ->Java  Build Path -> Source, and then look at the structure of the deployed application in Mule Standalone. That should give you an idea of how this works.

EDIT:

Your problem seems to be, that your resources are not included in the "classes" folder of your zip. You need them there, not in the META-INF subfolders. I could reproduce only one failing scenario: if you create a project in Mule Studio and export it without first running it or building it with command line Maven, the project might not be automatically built before the export, and the zip would then not include the classes folder where your resources are supposed to be. Try running your application with Run as Mule Application with Maven before exporting the zip. If that is not helping, try to build your application in command line with `mvn package`. Command line Maven will create the zip in the "target" folder of your application.

Comment: Thanks Anton.  I tried that and (in Mule Studio) got: ERROR 2014-02-12 15:25:13,066 [[gp_integration].config.change.6.thread.1] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: null
org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: _Failed to load "myTransform.groovy" from classpath or file system_

Comment: Looking in my .classpath file which seems to match your Properties ->Java Build Path -> Source I see   `<classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/resources" excluding="**/*.java"/>`

Comment: This is with the new version saying:      `<scripting:script engine="Groovy"  
        file="myTransform.groovy">  
    </scripting:script>`

Comment: Hmm... I get that error when it does a dynamic reload in Studio. If I stop it running in Studio and rebuild, it works. Regardless, whenever I deploy it to the standalone server I always get the error.

Comment: When I do the File -> Export... (with a rebuild) when it is running in Studio I get the error. When I do a rebuild without exporting, it builds and runs correctly in Studio. But it never works when being deployed.

Comment: Do you have the script in the "classes" folder in the deployed application? Or some other folder(s)? Also, please try again with a new/clean version of Mule Studio/Standalone, edit your question adding more info about your versions, or special log entries or configurations that might be relevant. This should work out-of-the-box.

Comment: Just use Maven to build your projects, you're going to need it anyway.

Comment: @Anton is this information useful?  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is where I went wrong, I put the myTransform.groovy file into the src/main/resources rather than importing it through the user interface.
Once I did import the file it was deployed in the classes folder.
Ugh.

Sincere thanks for the tips.
-- Don

Comment: What? Where does the script end then? `src/main/app`? Is it correctly embedded when you build the application zip?

Comment: I had physically put the file into the project's Studio directory src/main/resources rather than importing it as I should have. Now that it is imported, when deployed I see the script file in two places: `C:\mule-enterprise-standalone-3.3.0\apps\gp\classes` and `C:\mule-enterprise-standalone-3.3.0\apps\gp\META-INF\src\main\resources`. It works so I suppose it is correctly embedded.

Comment: Where does the file go in your Studio project when you import it?

Comment: I imported it into src/main/resources.

Comment: Wow, so it's back to square one basically, as this is where you placed it in the first place.

Comment: Yes but the difference was physical placement vs. import placement.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. The file is in the same location and is referred the same way, i.e. `<scripting:script engine="Groovy" file="myTransform.groovy"/>` so you should be able to obtain the same result by hand, without "importing" it.

Comment: I don't know, maybe there is some bookkeeping behind the scenes or perhaps my POM is in error. It works one way and not another. This was not a drag and drop onto the workbench, it was a directory-to-directory copy.

Comment: Sounds like when you import, Studio sets up the necessary build or class path config for you, ensuring that when you build your project,  files (or groovy files) in src/main/resources is stored to the classes folder.